# how can i replace ngx-lottie path to different one on the fly without creating a new element for that?

Tags: angular, lottie

I Am using [ngx-lottie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-lottie), and I am struggling to get to change the path (to the animation file)

```
this.lottieConfig = {
        path: 'assets/standBy.json',
        renderer: 'canvas',
        autoplay: true,
        loop: true
    };
```

How can I change the animation base on notifications from WebSocket I connected to without creating a new Lottie ? and without the animation jump while replacing? for example, I get notification of 'ready' i would like to replace the path of Lottie to 'assets/ready.json' 'if I just changing the path prop its not working.

Answer (score 1):

This is outlined in their docs. Set the new file in your websocket event handler like this:

```js
    this.lottieConfig= {
      ...this.lotteConfig, // In case you have other properties that you want to copy
      path: '/assets/new-animation.json',
    };
```

I'm not sure what you mean with animation jump but if you want the animation to finish first before replacing you could listen on the `loopComplete` event and wait for it to trigger.